# Show Visibility Toggle in custom content element

Tags: typo3

I have a simple content element set up, but the default Visibility toggle is not showing on the Access tab.

Here is my tt_content setup:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['my_element'] = [
        'showitem' => '
            --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
                 --palette--;;general,
                 --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.header;headers,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance,
                --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.frames;frames,
                --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.appearanceLinks;appearanceLinks,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:tabs.access,
                 --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.visibility;visibility,
                 --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:tabs.extended'
];
```

How do I enable the visibility toggle?

Answer (score 2):

In TYPO3 12 there is no palette "visibility". Which TYPO3 version you are using? Be sure that all needed fields are properly defined! Either in palette configuration or directly in showitem.
Use "Configuration" module to check your TCA configuration for tt_content table to be sure your configuration is really loaded and active.

Comment: Oh I see, I must have pulled that palette name from some outdated source. I am using version 10.

Answer (score 1):

***Answer for own custom tables, not fitting here as OP was asking for default core table tt_content. See [Karsten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76910952/1750509) for solution.***

You need to TCA-define that column. Check the `tt_content.hidden` from core for your LTS version:

https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/main/typo3/sysext/frontend/Configuration/TCA/tt_content.php#L231-L244 and copy that to your TCA.

The fields are auto-generated for the Database (see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FileStructure/ExtTablesSql.html#auto-generated-structure), but still you need a TCA column definition.

Comment: I don't really understand, all other fields show up in thier palettes, why do I need to define this one? Why would it need defining twice?

Comment: As long as you "only" work on existing tables and existing fields, there is nothing else to define. @NextThursday has confused this with *custum* tables.

Comment: Indeed, sry for that. Updated answer accordingly.